# How to change an image size perspective while scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way or a third party library that supports the image to be resizable while scrolling in Android, the same way contact images work in iPhone? I want the image to be large at first and to get smaller and smaller while scrolling down till it becomes of the smallest size and vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CoordinatorLayout`. It allows you to specify how a view will behave as you scroll. In the example below, you can see that the view collapses, using `layout_collapseMode`.  I suggest you check out this tutorial to learn more about what you can achieve with this kind of layout.

Here is the example XML (This example was taken from [here](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```